# How join two arrays in one?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, datatable

I have a problem with two arrangements that I need to join, my intention is the following, by means of a query to MySQL with PHP I recover the name of all my registered companies and the income for each month of said companies:

This is my query:

```
$totalEmpresas = $db->rawQuery('SELECT fecha, SUM(total) AS ingresosTotal from ingresos 
where YEAR(fecha) = "2021" AND ingresos.id_rol = ? AND ingresos.id_usuario = ? AND ingresos.empresa = ? 
GROUP BY MONTH(fecha)', Array ($idRolUser, $idUser, $idEmpresa));
```

This query returns me an array grouped by all the available months of each of the consulted companies, this is an example of the array that it returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fecha] => 2021-01-08
            [ingresosTotal] => 158181.17
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fecha] => 2021-02-05
            [ingresosTotal] => 781595.14
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fecha] => 2021-03-05
            [ingresosTotal] => 345094.65
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [fecha] => 2021-04-09
            [ingresosTotal] => 166694.76
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [fecha] => 2021-05-26
            [ingresosTotal] => 155874.65
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [fecha] => 2021-06-04
            [ingresosTotal] => 159801.81
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [fecha] => 2021-07-02
            [ingresosTotal] => 161689.9
        )

)
```

This is where I have the problem my intention is to form an array that has the following structure:

```
data:[
   {
     empresa = Empresa Ejemplo 1,
     2021-02-05 = 781595.14,
     2021-03-05 = 345094.65,
     2021-04-09 = 166694.76,
     2021-05-26 = 155874.65,
     2021-06-04 = 159801.81,
     2021-07-02 = 161689.9   
   },
   {
     empresa = Empresa Ejemplo 2,
     2021-02-05 = 781595.14,
     2021-03-05 = 345094.65,
     2021-04-09 = 166694.76,
     2021-05-26 = 155874.65,
     2021-06-04 = 159801.81,
     2021-07-02 = 161689.9   
   }
]
```

The problem is that my company and my dates are in two separate arrays, and if the one with array_push is as follows:

```
{"data":[
    {
       "Empresa":"Empresa Ejemplo 1",
       "Fechas":[
          {"January":158181.17},
          {"February":781595.14},
          {"March":345094.65},
          {"April":166694.76},
          {"May":155874.65},
          {"June":159801.81},
          {"July":161689.9}
       ]
     }
```

I tried using array_push inside foreach but this doesn't work work, this is my code:

```
function MensualIngreso($idRolUser, $idUser){

        require_once ("../vendor/thingengineer/mysqli-database-class/MysqliDb.php");
        $db = new MysqliDb (DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, '', DB_NAME);

        // Debemos cosultar los ingresos de las empresas globalmente y por mes
        // 1.- Seleccionaremos todas las empresas por rol y id de usuario

        $db->where ("id_rol", $idRolUser);
        $db->where ("id_usuario", $idUser);
        $empresas = $db->get ("empresas");

        // 2.- Por cada de una de las empresas recorreremos los meses que ha pagado

        $aura = [];
        $data['data'] = [];

        foreach ($empresas as $key => $value) {
            
            $idEmpresa = $value['id_empresa'];
            $empresa = $value['empresa'];
            $fechas = [];

            $totalEmpresas = $db->rawQuery('SELECT fecha, SUM(total) AS ingresosTotal from ingresos 
            where YEAR(fecha) = "2021" AND ingresos.id_rol = ? AND ingresos.id_usuario = ? AND ingresos.empresa = ? GROUP BY MONTH(fecha)', Array ($idRolUser, $idUser, $idEmpresa));

            //print_r($totalEmpresas);
            //return;

            foreach ($totalEmpresas as $key => $value) {
                
                array_push($fechas, array(strftime("%B", strtotime( $value['fecha'] )) => $value['ingresosTotal']) );                

            }

            //print_r($fechas);

            $consulta = array(
                "Empresa" => $empresa,
                "Fechas" => $fechas
            );

            array_push($data['data'], $consulta);          

        }

        //print_r($data);

        return $data;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of your main issues might be that you're trying to get the month from `$value['fecha_aportacion']` but that does not appear to exist in your SQL query. I think it should probably just be `$value['fecha']`.

I think this does what you're looking for:

```php
$array = [
    [
        'fecha' => '2021-01-08',
        'ingresosTotal' => '158181.17',
    ], 
    [
        'fecha' => '2021-02-05',
        'ingresosTotal' => '781595.14',
    ],
    [
        'fecha' => '2021-03-05',
        'ingresosTotal' => '345094.65',
    ],
    [
        'fecha' => '2021-04-09',
        'ingresosTotal' => '166694.76',
    ],
    [
        'fecha' => '2021-05-26',
        'ingresosTotal' => '155874.65',
    ],
    [
        'fecha' => '2021-06-04',
        'ingresosTotal' => '159801.81',
    ],
    [
        'fecha' => '2021-07-02',
        'ingresosTotal' => '161689.9',
    ],
];

$empresa = 'empresa ejemplo 1';

$fechas = [];
$fechas['empresa'] = $empresa;

foreach ($array as $value) {
    $fecha = strftime("%B", strtotime( $value['fecha'] ));
    $fechas[$fecha] = $value['ingresosTotal'];
}

echo json_encode($fechas, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```json
{
    "empresa": "empresa ejemplo 1",
    "January": "158181.17",
    "February": "781595.14",
    "March": "345094.65",
    "April": "166694.76",
    "May": "155874.65",
    "June": "159801.81",
    "July": "161689.9"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answare but I mean, I want to  make an object like this:

[
 empresa = empresa ejemplo 1,
"January": "158181.17",
"February": "781595.14",
]

I mean, one object for each company in my database with the name of the company and the month of that company

Comment: Okay. If I understand correctly, I updated the answer to do what I believe you're asking for.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean, thank you very much men, this problem was drive me crazy, thank you men